# How to format a string in UTC to the configured timezone on Moment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

I have the following string, which is in UTC:

`2022-02-01T00:00:00Z`

I have already configured my timezone, so I do not want to mess/call `.tz()`

I know that this string is in UTC, but I am not managing to convert from UTC to the defined timezone, which in this example is `pacific/wallis`.

I have tried many things, as

```
const utc = moment.utc('2022-02-01T00:00:00Z').toDate()
const inConfiguredTimeZone = utc.format()
```

My desire is to get this timestamp `2022-02-01T00:00:00Z` and have converted to the defined timezone on `Moment`

I need to tell moment that "This string is in UTC, please give me the converted timestamp in the defined time zone"

Comment: So your desired output is `2022-02-01T12:00:00+12:00`?

Comment: Hey @derpirscher , is pacific/wallis 12 hours ahead of UTC? This timezone is dynamic, also the utc strings as well, so I have used these as examples. The timezone is defined in a higher level of abstraction. I am breaking my head trying to figure how to convert strings in UTC to whatever the defined timezone in moment is

Comment: I think the problems is `.utc`. Try it without the `Z` in the original string already tells moment it's in UTC. Also be aware that moment is no longer actively maintained, so for new code you should switch to luxon.

Comment: So what *is* your desired ouput?

Comment: Well, I have two issues.

The desired output is to convert strings in the format which I have presented, which I know is in UTC to whatever the defined timezone is in moment. 

In this example, with pacific/wallis, i would like to have the output in the same format, but with +12 hours, but assuming that the timezone is ```.tz('pacific/wallis')``` in this example

Comment: Don't *describe* your output, show the *exact string* you expect ...

Comment: as in my example hours are 0, midnight, it would be "2022-02-02T00:00:00Z". But this is dynamic, so it is impossible to say what the strings should be. 

- assume that timezone is defined = ```.tz('pacific/wallis')```
- get a string in UTC
- convert to the whatever the time is in the defined timezone

Comment: That is again a UTC timestamp, that is *24 hours*  later than your original input? I don't get it what you really want?

Comment: the timestamp that I want to convert is not the current time. It is a collection of strings, with hundreds of different time stamps, all in UTC. I want to display all of them in the timezone defined in Moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to format a UTC timestamp in your current timezone  (determined by your computer's time settings) just use

```
let s = moment("2022-02-01T00:00:00Z").format();
```

This will produce a string like `2022-02-01T12:00:00+12:00` if you are currently in a timezone that has a UTC offset of +12 hours (like pacific/wallis) or `2022-02-01T01:00:00+01:00` if you are currently in a timezone that has a UTC offset of +1 hours (like europe/berlin)

If you want it converted to a specific timezone use

```
let s = moment("2022-02-01T00:00:00Z").tz("pacific/wallis").format();
```

This will produce `2022-02-01T12:00:00+12:00`, regardless of your current timezone.

Comment: Thanks! I have realized that moment(utcTimeStamp).format() works!

the only thing I need to know, is what is the string format that I need to pass in ```.format()``` to keep this exact format```YYYY-MM-DDT23:00:00Z```. From the ```T``` to the right, I have no idea on how to pass

Comment: You **don't want** the `Z` in your result string! That `Z` is the indication that that timestamp is a *UTC* timestamp ...

Comment: oh I see. Thanks =D  So how do I keep the ```YYYY-MM-DD``` +  hours, minutes and seconds, implicitly passing it to ```.format()```?

Comment: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/